# Problems with entry names encoding when using ZipArchive in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, zip, c#-ziparchive

I have a method that takes a `IFormFile` with a `.zip` extension and reads the files that are zipped inside it. It works well, however, there are cases in which the encoding of the symbols `æ, å, ø` is wrong and they are represented as question marks. This doesn't happen every time, I will give some examples here.

This is how the code looks like

```
var stream = file.OpenReadStream(); // This here is the stream from the IFormFile
var archive = new ZipArchive(stream);

foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
{
    // Do something with the entries
}
```

When the problem appears the `entry.Name` can look like something like this `Tilbud 2 - Det r�de hus.pdf`.

I have tried giving props to the `ZipArchive` constructor as such

```
var archive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Read, false, Encoding.ASCII);
```

When the encoding is `ASCII`, the file names look like this - `Tilbud 2 - Det r?de hus.pdf`.

And when I try the `Encoding.Unicode`, the corrupted symbols take the value of the question mark (not sure if the example I am giving is with the actual number) - `Tilbud 2 - Det r\u300de hus.pdf`

The front-end is just axios post request. My though is that some zips have a different encoding when they come to the back-end and that is why sometimes those symbols work.

I have also tried changing the encoding of the `IFormFile` stream to UTF-8 before calling the `ZipArchive`, but this was not that straightforward, so I fist wanted to find out if that is actually the problem.

Feel free to ask questions and give suggestions for the strange behaviour.

Comment: Try `Encoding.UTF8`  it needs to be whatever the original zip was

Comment: With `Encoding.UTF8` it still puts the `�` instead of the symbol that it should

Comment: I'm guessing then that the zip is incorrectly encoded in the first place. Probably it's using the wrong code page. According to the spec, only ANSI and UTF-8 are supported. I suggest you check whatever it is that creates this zip. See also comments to the code for `ZipArchive` https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/0f06edefe1588d27de716af5805a20ca918c5f46/src/libraries/System.IO.Compression/src/System/IO/Compression/ZipArchive.cs#L368

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not worked with net6 `ZipArchive` class, so this is not direct answer. But per my previous experience with a zip archives, you can get literally any encoding of the filenames inside an archive, including very exotic one. And as I know there is no standard place into the archive where the exact encoding may be stored for future usage during the decompress. At the same time for success decompress you should use exactly the same encoding as was used during compression.

Personally I ended up with heuristic encoding detection using `chardetsharp` (https://github.com/superstrom/chardetsharp). This significantly increased success rate for unpacking but do not solved problem entirely (i.e. I still have some archives with decompression errors or with incorrect filenames, when the encoding is predicted incorrectly).

Sample usage with `SharpCompress` library (don't know how to integrate this into`ZipArchive` from a BCL):

```
    var arch = ArchiveFactory.Open(path,
        new SharpCompress.Readers.ReaderOptions
        {
            LookForHeader = true,
            ArchiveEncoding = new SharpCompress.Common.ArchiveEncoding
            {
                CustomDecoder  = CustomDecoder
            }
        });

    arch.WriteToDirectory(targetDir, new SharpCompress.Common.ExtractionOptions
    {
        ExtractFullPath=true,
    });

    private static string CustomDecoder(byte[] arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
    {
        var bytesToRead = arg1.Skip(arg2).Take(arg3).ToArray();
        if (bytesToRead.Length == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var det = new Mozilla.CharDet.UniversalDetector();
        det.HandleData(bytesToRead);
        det.DataEnd();
        var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(det.DetectedCharsetName ?? Encoding.UTF8.BodyName);

        return enc.GetString(bytesToRead);
    }
```

Looks like the `chardetsharp` implementation that I used does not have a nuget package. This was not a problem for my particular task and I simply cloned the `chardetsharp` sources and added `\src\CharDet\CharDet.csproj` to the solution and then used it as a `ProjectReference`. Then I called `chardetsharp` inside my `CustomDecoder` as shown above.

In production, you can try to use another encoding detection library, for example `NChardet` (https://github.com/thinksea/NChardet) which is also a C# port of the original Mozilla library, so it should have a similar API (but I have not used it, so I'm not sure) and have a nuget package.

Comment: So, I will accept your answer because it helped me solve it. As you said, the encoding of the file was the problem. What I did is I used `SharpCompress`  since it supports more encodings than `ZipArchive`. As @Charlieface mentioned, the `ZipArchive` is pretty limited. One very entry-level question though (sorry if it doesn't make sence). It works for me when I use UTF-8 as a hardcoded encoding, but how do I use the `chardetsharp` to determine the encoding? I didn't find a nuget package or some examples on how to have the code with the namespace and everything. Again, sorry if I am too dumb :)

Comment: I have updated the answer with details on how to integrate `chardetsharp` into your project. Unfortunately, there is no nuget package, so the way is a little bit weird.